# ImportError: cannot import name Side in `df.to_excel`

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, xlrd

While running `df.to_excel('Lesson3.xlsx', index=False)`, i am getting the below error,

```
from openpyxl.styles import Side
```

> ImportError: cannot import name Side

I tried below things but all in vane,

pip install pandas

```
pip install xlrd
pip3 install --upgrade pandas --force-reinstall
pip3 install --upgrade xlrd --force-reinstall
```

Below are more details of the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Pandas Tutorials/lesson3_write_excel.py", line 40, in <module>
    df.to_excel('Lesson3.xlsx', index=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1766, in to_excel
    engine=engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 652, in write
    freeze_panes=freeze_panes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1404, in write_cells
    style_kwargs = self._convert_to_style_kwargs(cell.style)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1074, in _convert_to_style_kwargs
    new_v = _conv_to_x(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1310, in _convert_to_border
    v = cls._convert_to_side(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1253, in _convert_to_side
    from openpyxl.styles import Side
ImportError: cannot import name Side
```

Comment: Have you installed `openpyxl`?

Comment: Awesome, please put this in answer so i can mark it as one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install `openpyxl` that is used by `df.to_excel()`.